# Visual Studio Code .Net Core debugging error 'source code is different from original'

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-core, visual-studio-code

*(I refer Visual Studio Code as vscode)*

I am working on Asp.Net Mvc project with .Net Core 2.2. If I do not modify the source code after I open vscode, I can debug/run the project within vscode without any problem. But after I modify the source code, if I debug, vscode gives me warning

```
Breakpoint warning: The source code is different from the original version. To allow this breakpoint to be hit: Add '"requireExactSource": false' to launch.json and restart debugging.
```

when i put a breakpoint and it comes disabled automatically. Also i can not see the last changes in the running project.

To be able to see the last modifications, I have to debug with Visual Studio once, and then if I debug/run the source code with vscode again, no problem till I modify the source code again.

**How can I fix this situation?**

Note: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693211/visual-studio-code-breakpoint-warning-the-source-code-is-different-from-the-ori) but it says s/he can not use breakpoints since first run and the problem is related to dotnet path. My problem is completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** check if vscode is building the right project/solution. **`dotnet build` the main/entrance/single project does not build other dependency projects.**

The root of the problem comes from tasks.json for me. The target for the build task was set wrong. It only builds a single project of a whole solution while the work is done on other projects of the solution.

**My fix** was modifying the building task to build the whole solution instead of a single project.

Debugging with Visual Studio was fixing the problem temporarly because it was building the whole solution which reflects the last modifications.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61350608/7711454) is also related to this question.

[Sample launch.json and tasks.json for .Net core](https://dev.to/bitsmonkey/launch-net-core-with-vscode-for-starters-2ce5).